# How Can I Debug React-Virtualized's InfiniteScroll/Grid Fetching?

Tags: react-virtualized

I've got a React Virtualized InfiniteList/Grid combination, following the basic pattern from the documentation (https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/InfiniteLoader.md#infiniteloader-and-grid).

It works great, except for two things:

- If I scroll too fast, instead of waiting for things to catch up, it resets the scroll to the top of the grid
- The combo only fetches the first N results (eg. 125) ... even though I have 859 results (and even though I have provided 859 as the `rowCount` prop)

  - This is especially strange because it fetches in increments of 25, so this means that everything works fine the first 5 times and then inexplicably fails on the 6th.

I've tried everything I can to figure out what's going on, and even when I fill the React Virtualized code with `console.log` and `debugger` statements I still can't figure out why it stops at 125 results (or why fast scrolls reset).

Can anyone more familiar with React Virtualized point me to the spot in the code where it decides whether to keep fetching or stop (and possibly reset the start index to 0)?  I can tell that the InfiniteScroll's `onRowsRendered` and `scanForUnloadedRanges` and Grid's`onSectionRendered` are involved, but I still can't figure out where the value processing stops and the actual "decide whether to keep going" logic begins.

Comment: Attach a Plnkr with an example of what' you're doing.

Comment: Unfortunately there's too much code involved to create an example.  However, I'm not looking for a fix to my specific issue, just trying to understand how React-Virtualized works (and in particular where it decides whether to keep fetching or stop).

Comment: Well I'm probably saying what you already know, but, the component that decides when to load data is `InfiniteLoader` which is here: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/InfiniteLoader/InfiniteLoader.js. It's not too big so maybe it would be worth scanning through the source. I also wrote a how-to guide for one way to use `InfiniteLoader` here: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/creatingAnInfiniteLoadingList.md and another example here: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/InfiniteLoader.md#infiniteloader-and-list

Comment: "_Can anyone more familiar with React Virtualized point me to the spot in the code where it decides whether to keep fetching or stop_" I think you're looking for this: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/29752372a7ceae441564fe29795c427d1ccb0bc3/source/InfiniteLoader/InfiniteLoader.js#L159-L187

Comment: Maybe the disconnect is that you don't realize that your application is expected to keep track of which rows have been loaded (and are loading)? `InfiniteLoader` itself isn't stateful. This is illustrated in the 2 examples I posted above though.

Comment: I was having the same "reset to 0" issue, and it was because I was returning undefined from the row renderer in some cases.  When I returned a placeholder string instead, it stopped doing the scrolling reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @brianvaughn's suggested in his comment, the `InfinititeLoader` component (https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/InfiniteLoader/InfiniteLoader.js) is partly responsible.  Whenever rows are rendered `_loadUnloadedRanges` method gets called from `scanForUnloadedRanges`, and it handles loading the ranges that `scanForUnloadedRanges` found.

However, that's only part of the equation.  The parameters that are passed in to `onRowsRendered` come from `Grid`.  The `Grid` `_updateScrollTopForScrollToRow` method gets called as the user scrolls, and that method has the following line:

```
const targetIndex = Math.max(0, Math.min(rowCount - 1, scrollToRow))
```

That `targetIndex` will ultimately affect which rows get loaded, and as you can see it depends on the `rowCount` that is passed in initially.

This is what caused problems for me.  I started with an `InfiniteLoader` + `List` combination, and in that setup a "row" means the same thing to both components.  However I then switched to a `InfiniteLoader` + `Grid` combination, and to a `Grid` a "row" is an array of `InfiniteLoader` rows.  In other words, a `Grid` "row" is a row of cells, but an `InfiniteLoader` "row" is a cell.

My method for calculating the `rowCount` was changed to use the `Grid` definition of a "row", but since it was being passed to `InfinniteLoader` I should have used `InfiniteLoader`'s definition of a "row" instead.  In other words, I should have returned just `numItems`, not `numItems/columnCount`.

All this could have easily been avoided if the React Virtualized used an "items" prop for `InfiniteLoader` instead of using a name that's also used (with two different meanings) by two other React Virtualized components ... but at least now I have a *much* better understanding of how these components work.